# Does a stand-by Quartz Scheduler require some kind of refresh for starting?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I'm using Quartz with Spring Boot, specifically using it's conveniences through the SchedulerFactoryBean abstraction. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-quartz.html.

I need to start the Scheduler manually instead, for which I think of using schedulerFactoryBean.setAutoStartup(false) and then Scheduler.start() in a class with an Scheduler instance autowired. See example code below.

```
@Configuration
public class QuartzConfig implements SchedulerFactoryBeanCustomizer {

 public static final int STARTUP_DELAY = 5;

 @Autowired
 private DataSource dataSource;

 @Override
 public void customize(SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean) {
   schedulerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
   schedulerFactoryBean.setStartupDelay(STARTUP_DELAY);
   schedulerFactoryBean.setAutoStartup(false);
   schedulerFactoryBean.setWaitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown(TRUE);
 }

} 

@Service
public class SchedulerService {

  private final Scheduler scheduler;

  @Autowired
  public SchedulerService(Scheduler scheduler) {
     this.scheduler = scheduler;
  }

  public void startScheduler() {
     this.scheduler.start();
  }
}
```

However, there will be other instances in other nodes running on the database. My question is, does this not-started Scheduler instance refresh or becomes aware of all the work done by the other instance? Does a stand-by Quartz Scheduler require some kind of refresh manually triggered for starting?

For example, if a trigger, job or something else is added, changed or deleted will the not-started one be aware (cache refresh?) of it after the code calls .start()?

I have read several pages of quartz and I couldnt really find an aswer for this. I couldnt find a place that explains if or how an instance sincronizes itself with external changes done to its database.

Comment: Jobs can be synchronized within a cluster either via specific tables in Database or via Terracotta. See details at http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/configuration/. Also you can configure some of your jobs to be non-concurrent, which means that that only one job instance is guaranteed to be executed at the same time

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko When you say that "Jobs can be synchronized within a cluster either via specific tables in Database" you mean that it automatically does it, dont you? Or you mean some kind of manual sync?

Comment: @Silver, short answer -- yes. But first you need to do some preparations: 1) create quartz tables in DB (for example using Liquibase) 2) provide datasource settings in `quartz.properties`. 3) tell the job that it must be non-concurrent by denoting its class with `@DisallowConcurrentExecution`